# В чем отличие в функционировании брандмауэра и прокси-сервера?

Tags: сеть, информатика

Рассматриваю абстрактный брандмауэр, не только от Microsoft

Comment: проще, вероятно, сказать, что у этих программ общего: и та и другая обрабатывают информацию, поступающую из сети. и то на совершенно разных уровнях модели osi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Брандмауэр. Обычно предназначен для локальной защиты компьютера/сервера от вторжения, закрытия/открытия портов и т.п. В общем, уровень первичной безопасности для АРМ;
2. Прокси-сервер больше предназначен для осуществления безопасности более высокого уровня (для подсети/сети), с выполнением функционала шлюза в интернет с/без авторизацией пользователя, наблюдением за траффиком, и т.п.
   Как верно отметил @aleksandr barakin - их задачи зависят от их уровня обработки инфы.